# Why is modulus different in different programming languages?

Tags: perl, vbscript, tcl, modulo

Perl

```
print 2 % -18;
```

-->

```
-16
```

Tcl

```
puts [expr {2 % -18}]
```

-->

```
-16
```

but VBScript

```
wscript.echo 2 mod -18
```

-->

```
2
```

Why the difference?

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I've tested in Python, Ruby, Javascript and bash now. JS and bash both said 2 and the other said -16.

Comment: Modulo operations mainly belong to Counting numbers and are arbitrarily defined outside of that.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The [wikipedia answer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) is fairly helpful here.

A short summary is that any integer can be defined as

a = qn + r

where all of these letters are integers, and

0 <= |r| < |n|.

Almost every programming language will require that (a/n) * n + (a%n) = a. So the definition of modulus will nearly always depend on the definition of integer division. There are two choices for integer division by negative numbers 2/-18 = 0 or 2/-18 = -1. Depending on which one is true for your language will usually change the % operator.

This is because 2 = (-1) * -18 + (-16) and 2 = 0 * -18 + 2.

For Perl the situation is complicated. [The manual page](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Multiplicative-Operators) says: "Note that when use integer is in scope, "%" gives you direct access to the modulus operator as implemented by your C compiler. This operator is not as well defined for negative operands, but it will execute faster. " So it can choose either option for Perl (like C) if use integer is in scope. If use integer is not in scope, the manual says " If $b is negative, then $a % $b is $a minus the smallest multiple of $b that is not less than $a (i.e. the result will be less than or equal to zero). "

Comment: Re "can do anything", no.  If use integer is in scope it can only do what C does, and the C standard explicitly requires (a/n) + (a%n) = a but allows either choice for integer division.

Comment: (100/2)+(100%2) != 100 ... am I missing something?

Comment: @B T, oops, missed out a factor of n, thanks for spot, I'll fix it

Answer (score 9):

Wikipedia's ["Modulo operation"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) page explains it quite well. I won't try to do any better here, as I'm likely to make a subtle but important mistake.

The rub of it is that you can define "remainder" or "modulus" in different ways, and different languages have chosen different options to implement.

Comment: I think your original answer struck right at the heart it.  Sometimes '%' means "remainder" and sometimes it means "modulus", which aren't the same thing.

Comment: @Bill: I wasn't sure about deleting it, but then it comes down to the definition of "remainder" and "modulus" which are *also* (apparently) not as clear cut as one would like.

Answer (score 4):

After dividing a number and a divisor, one of which is negative, you have at least two ways to separate them into a quotient and a remainder, such that quotient * divisor + remainder = number:  you can either round the quotient towards negative infinity, or towards zero.

Many languages just choose one.

I can't resist pointing out that [Common Lisp](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mod_r.htm) offers both.

Answer (score 3):

python, of course, explicitly informs you

```
>>> divmod(2,-18)
(-1, -16)
```